# How to distribute ruby software in debian environments

Tags: ruby, debian

How to easily package software that uses multiple gems into a debian installable packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options

1) package your application as a gem using [jeweler](http://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler)
  By making it a gem, you can specify dependencies in the gemspec, so when it is installed
  rubygems will automatically attempt to install the needed gems.

This is probably the easiest thing

2) run an apt-server and package your app for it. There are some instructions on running an 
   apt server on the [ubuntu help pages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LocalAptGetRepository).
   Packaging your app is somewhat complicated looking, but boils down to:

- writing install/uninstall etc scripts
- writing config files

Get started with [this doc on the ibm developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-debpkg.html)